# What are best practices for writing tests for a Sinatra API?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, sinatra, bdd

Specifically, I would like to know how to separate unit and acceptance tests.

Unit test looks like:

```
it 'creates bar' do
  expect {
    post '/foo/bar'
  }.to change{ Bar.count }.by 1
end
```

This is mix of a unit test and an acceptance test. But I don't understand how to separate them.

The API `app/bar.rb` file:

```
post '/foo/bar' do
  Bar.create
  status 202
end
```

Also, any relevant links are appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't be done interacting with the page? Simulating real users? Witch clicks, filling forms etc? https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: It's an API. There is no page.

Comment: In that case you should test it the way someone would use it. With Net::HTTP ? :)

Comment: You should test you model separate from API, this mean you should have bar_spec in your spec/models. For API, usually, you create api_spec tests in your spec/requests folder. API Test should check response.status and response.body